# The correct login page pattern

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, material-ui

I am sorry for my stupid question but i am really new in react and this problem make me stuck for days. I am kinda confused to make a login page in reactjs. my app.js code is like this :

```
import React from 'react';
import {HashRouter as Router, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import asyncComponent from './AsyncComponent';
import AppShell from './AppShell';
import Login from './login/Login';

const Dashboard = asyncComponent(() => {
  return import(/* webpackChunkName: "dashboard" */ './dashboard/Dashboard')
    .then(module => module.default);
});

const LoginPage = asyncComponent(() => {
  return import(/* webpackChunkName: "login" */ './login/Login')
    .then(module => module.default);
});

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Router>
                <AppShell>
                    <div>
                        <Route exact path="/" component={Dashboard} />
                        <Route path="/login" component={LoginPage} />
                    </div>
                </AppShell>
            </Router>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

And this is my AppShell code :

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import {MuiThemeProvider} from 'material-ui/styles';
import {AppBar, Drawer, MenuItem} from 'material-ui';
import {DashboardIcon} from './icon/Icons';
import ArrowDropRight from 'material-ui/svg-icons/navigation-arrow-drop-right';

const ContentStyle = {
  width: '90%',
  margin: 'auto',
  marginTop: '30px'
};

class SidebarDrawer extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    let frameCount = 0;
    const open = () => (frameCount++ > 0) ? this.props.onMounted() :
      requestAnimationFrame(open);
    requestAnimationFrame(open);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Drawer
        docked={false}
        width={200}
        open={this.props.open}
        onRequestChange={this.props.onRequestChange}
      >
        <MenuItem
          primaryText={'Dashboard'}
          leftIcon={<DashboardIcon/>}
          containerElement={<Link to={'/'}/>}
          onClick={this.props.onClick}
        />
      </Drawer>
    );
  }
}

class AppShell extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      open: false,
      drawer : false
    };
  }

  handleDrawerToggle = (e) => {
    if (!this.state.drawer) {
      this.setState({drawer: true});
      e.preventDefault();
    } else {
      this.setState({open: !this.state.open});
    }
  }

  render() {
    const LazySidebarDrawer = this.state.drawer && (<SidebarDrawer
      open={this.state.open}
      onMounted={() => this.setState({open: true})}
      onClick={() => this.setState({open: false})}
      onRequestChange={open => this.setState({open: open})}
    />)

    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider>
        <div>
          <AppBar
            title="Dashboard"
            iconClassNameRight="muidocs-icon-navigation-expand-more"
            onLeftIconButtonTouchTap={this.handleDrawerToggle}
          />
          {LazySidebarDrawer}
          <div id="content" style={ContentStyle}>
            {React.cloneElement(this.props.children)}
          </div>
        </div>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }
};

export default AppShell;
```

But i still can access dashboard when i open login page. How is the correct pattern for login page?

[image: Here is a capture]

Thanks

Comment: paste code for AppShell.

Comment: @Tomasz Mularczyk, oh ya, sorry i forgot that. i updated my question

Answer (score 1):

Your routing is correct, the exact '/' will only render the Dashboard component when the path is '/'. What you're seeing is the dashboard drawer or AppBar component. The dashboard drawer is still there in the login screen because it's always there in the AppShell code and your routes are children of AppShell. A potential solution would be to move that AppBar component to your Dashboard component if you only want it there.

Comment: yeah thats the one.. still figure how to move AppBar to Dashboard page. Thank you for your answer anyway.

Comment: Can you put it in the render like in the AppShell component?